# Spark's Jetty autoreload

Tags: jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, spark-java

is it possible to setup Spark's Jetty to automatically reload when changes are made in java class? I was trying to setup jetty-maven-plugin to do so, but it just runs another simultaneous Jetty server scanning only webapp folder for changes and presenting them on localhost:8080. While Spark's Jetty (which is shown on localhost:4567) has to be manually restarted. Thank you for answer.

Comment: I'm also restarting the server manually after declaring any new route and would appreciate an easier approach.

Answer (score -1):

Start your Spark Java program with the following JVM args:

```
-Djetty.reload=automatic -Djetty.scanIntervalSeconds=2
```

Comment: To me this does not seem to work with Gradle  "gradle run -Djetty.reload=automatic -Djetty.scanIntervalSeconds=2"

Comment: @StephanSchmidt were you able to implement auto reload? If yes, can you share more details?

Comment: This solution doesn't work properly, at least as of February 2017.